# call explore.exe with path from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have crate a registry at user system. And i want when user click on my image button that is in my gridview. I shall call url protocol from registry and execute the `Explorer.exe` with path that i will assign with the image button on the grid.

I create registry that is below

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PicPath]
@="URL: MPath Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PicPath\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PicPath\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PicPath\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe\""
```

the problem is that when i add 
   `@="\"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe\ " "%1`

%1 is for parameter when i pass `c:\Logs` my system start to open infinite explorer in taskbar. But when i use `@="\"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe\""` its open explore perfect on client system. But i want that explorer.exe open certain path on client system.

below is my code that i try

```
protected void grdOrderList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
     a.HRef = "MPath:OpenForm " + "/root,C:\\Abc";
     a.ID = "a1";

     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
     img.ID = "img1";

     img.Visible = true;
     img.ImageUrl = @"~\images\blue_camera.png";
     a.Controls.Add(img);
     e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(a);
}
```

So how can i do this . Thanks for you time

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void grdOrderList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
   a.HRef = "MPath:OpenForm " + "/root,C:\\Abhishek";
   a.ID = "a1";

   //System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
   //img.ID = "img1";

   //img.Visible = true;
   //img.ImageUrl = @"~\images\blue_camera.png";

   var img = new ImageButton();
   img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(img_Click);
   a.Controls.Add(img);
   e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(a);
}

protected void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\blah.txt");
}
```

Comment: `IExplore` is _Internet_ explorer not _Windows_ explorer.

Comment: @davidarnol process.Start will run on server side not client side